# When a variable is declared in a T-SQL stored procedure, is it kept in memory or tempdb?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, tempdb

We're trying to optimize some of our T-SQL stored procedures to reduce tempdb contention, but I can't figure out how non-table variables are stored by SQL server:

- What about simple data types like INT and DATETIME?  It feels like they'd live in memory.
- What about VARCHARs/VARCHAR(MAX)?  A regular VARCHAR could live in memory, but a VARCHAR(MAX) might need to use tempdb for its storage.
- Table variables are stored in tempdb.  These I'm not really interested in though.

The [MSDN article on tempdb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190768.aspx) doesn't explain regular variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The Capacity Planning article for tempdb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345368.aspx) answers your questions:

> The large object data types are varchar(max), nvarchar(max),
>   varbinary(max) text, ntext, image, and xml. These types can be up to 2
>   GB in size and can be used as variables or parameters in stored
>   procedures, user-defined functions, batches, or queries. Parameters
>   and variables that are defined as a LOB data type use main memory as
>   storage if the values are small. However, large values are stored in
>   tempdb. When LOB variables and parameters are stored in tempdb, they
>   are treated as internal objects. You can query the
>   sys.dm_db_session_space_usage dynamic management view to report the
>   pages allocated to internal objects for a given session.

The article is worth reading in its entirety, because it also covers a lot of the other uses for tempdb.

EDIT: If you're curious how much memory in tempdb a specific session is using, you can run the following query:

```
select * 
from sys.dm_db_session_space_usage 
where session_id = @@SPID
```

Using this, it didn't look like my `VARCHAR(MAX)` variable was stored in tempdb until it reached around 1000 KB in size... but I'm sure that varies based on the memory that your server has available.

Comment: Thanks for finding this!  I assume "if the values are small" means less than 8000 bytes?  Regardless, the article seems to imply that non-MAX (N)VARCHARs and small variables are stored in memory.

Answer (score 2):

"**Table variables are stored in tempdb.** These I'm not really interested in though."

In general yes, table variables are stored in tempdb, but this could be changed with memory-optimized table variables.

[Faster temp table and table variable by using memory optimization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/faster-temp-table-and-table-variable-by-using-memory-optimization?view=sql-server-2017)

> ## D. Scenario: Table variable can be MEMORY_OPTIMIZED=ON
>
> A traditional table variable represents a table in the tempdb database. For much faster performance you can memory-optimize your table variable.
>
> The inline syntax does not support memory-optimization. So let us convert the inline syntax to the explicit syntax for the TYPE.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.typeTableD AS TABLE  
(  
    Column1  INT   NOT NULL INDEX ix1,  
    Column2  CHAR(10)  
) WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON);

DECLARE @tvTableD dbo.typeTableD;
INSERT INTO @tvTableD (Column1) values (1), (2);  

SELECT * FROM @tbTableD;
```

> A memory-optimized table variable does not reside in tempdb. Memory-optimization results in speed increases that are often 10 times faster or more.