# Where is a Table Variable created in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, programming-languages

I would like to know where is the table variable created in a computer?

Let's say I declare a table variable as @emp in SQL server, can someone please help to understand where is a table variable created?

Comment: please review this answer. [When a variable is declared in a T-SQL stored procedure, is it kept in memory or tempdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728775/when-a-variable-is-declared-in-a-t-sql-stored-procedure-is-it-kept-in-memory-or)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Table variables** are alternatives of temporary tables which store a set of records.

**Table variable** `(@emp)` is created in the memory. Whereas, a **Temporary table** `(#temp)` is created in the t**empdb database**. 
Note:- if there is a memory pressure the pages belonging to a table variable may be pushed to **tempdb**.

The syntax of a table variable is shown below:

```
Declare @emp Table
(
            [EmpID] [int] NULL,
            [EmpName] [varchar](30) NULL,
)
```

Inserting a value into the **table variable**:

```
Declare @emp Table
(
            [EmpID] [int] NULL,
            [EmpName] [varchar](30) NULL,

)

INSERT INTO @emp (EmpID, EmpName) values (1, 'Rohatash')

Select * from @emp
```

Answer (score 0):

table variables are created within tempdb. refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/tempdb-database?view=sql-server-2017

tempdb is stored on disk, and you can check for the file location by right clicking on

```
[yourserver] > Databases > System Databases > tempdb
```

In the properties window, you can find the physical file location in the `Files` tab.

Comment: This is not always the case. It could reside memory(memory-optimized filegroup) https://stackoverflow.com/a/55435833/5070879